# Symfony2 - Multiple CDN configuration

Tags: symfony, twig, package, cdn, assets

I´m trying to setup two different CDN´s in my Symfony2 project.
With just one CDN, everything works fine with the following setup:

*config.yml*

```
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    assets_base_urls:
        http: [http://cdn.blabla.com]
        ssl: []
```

After a few hours of research, I´ve seen there´s a way of setting up more than just one CDN:

*config.yml*

```
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    assets_base_urls:
        http: []
        ssl: []
    packages:
        cdn:
            base_urls:
                http: ["http://cdn.blabla.com"]
                ssl: []
        cdn-static:
            base_urls:
                http: ["http://cdn-static.blabla.com"]
                ssl: []
```

When trying:
{{ asset('/path/to/resource.ext','cdn') }}

It works really good, getting a URL like this:
*http://cdn.blabla.com/path/to/resource.ext*

But when doing:
{{ asset('/path/to/resource.ext','cdn-static') }}

It comes up with "**An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("There is no "cdn-static" asset package.")**"

I´m using **Symfony2 v2.0.15** and **Twig v1.8.2**

Any clue on what can it be happening?

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: I'm not sure but, did you try rename cdn-static to cdn_static?

Comment: Wtf...it worked! :D
Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*config.yml*

```
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    assets_base_urls:
        http: []
        ssl: []
    packages:
        cdn:
            base_urls:
                http: ["http://cdn.blabla.com"]
                ssl: []
        cdn_static:
            base_urls:
                http: ["http://cdn-static.blabla.com"]
                ssl: []
```